# XSLT 2.0 for-each-group, sum based on parent value

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I have tried to get `for-each-group` to work without success in my xml, I want to group the areas in my refdes-tags ond calculate the sum of the prices per area.

If I have several refdes with the same area under an item it does only count the first one in the sum but I want all to be counted.

Input:

```
<part>
    <bom>
        <item partnumber="1">
            <refdes area="area1">010</refdes>
            <price>0.5</price>
        </item>
        <item partnumber="2">
            <refdes area="area2">020</refdes>
            <price>1.0</price>
        </item>
        <item partnumber="3">
            <refdes area="area1">030</refdes>
            <refdes area="area1">060</refdes>
            <refdes area="area2">070</refdes>
            <price>0.3</price>
        </item>
    </bom>
</part>
```

xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes" /> 
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table class="sortable" id="odd">
            <tr>
                <th>Area</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="part/bom/item/refdes" group-by="@area">
                <xsl:sort select="@area" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
                <xsl:element name="tr">
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/../price)" />
                    </td>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table class="sortable" id="odd">
   <tr>
      <th>Area</th>
      <th>Price</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>area1</td>
      <td>0.8</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>area2</td>
      <td>1.3</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Wanted output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table class="sortable" id="odd">
   <tr>
      <th>Area</th>
      <th>Price</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>area1</td>
      <td>1.1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>area2</td>
      <td>1.3</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that for the case where the `area` attribute is "area1", there are only two `price` nodes involved. The `sum` function will not sum the same node more than once. (Change `sum` to `count` and you will see it return 2).

Try changing the statement to this instead

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(for $ref in current-group() return $ref/../price)" />
```